# Passenger on Ubuntu still only serving default index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Trying to get my server to serve my rails apps.

I have a test app installed, apache2 and passenger have been installed have I have added the following to the apache2.conf

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
      ServerName 192.168.1.67
      DocumentRoot /home/john/Public/test-app
</VirtualHost>
```

Clearly, I am misunstanding something, because I think that should redirect calls to my local IP to my rails app. It is not. It is going to the default apache index.html.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED answer: 
I think you are missing the "Directory" node. try using this config code:

(assuming your project path is: /home/john/Public/test-app)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/john/Public/test-app/public
    RailsEnv development
    <Directory /home/john/Public/test-app/public>
    AllowOverride all 
    Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have my answer updated so that you could copy&paste into your own apache config file.

Comment: won't this just try to serve files in `public/` directory i.e. `404.html`, `favicon` -- not the actual rails app?

Comment: mmcrae: no. Passenger will handle this correctly, which is written on its offical document.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdomain.betamaster.us
    DocumentRoot /var/www_home/mysubdomain/
</VirtualHost>
```

After applying these changes make sure to execute

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

in order to reload the server configuration.

Comment: what should I make server name? it's a local machine that doesn't have a domain name, or sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms in this question but it was a different problem. My apache install already had a Virtual host enabled, so I had to disable it and enable my own with the commands

```
sudo a2dissite default
sudo a2ensite myapp
```

where default was the name of the Virtual Host file included by default in sites-avaliable/ and myapp is the file i added.

Hopefully this helps someone.